# Are there any text field guidelines for web pages?

Tags: testing, web

I'm trying to find the does and don'ts for implementing text fields for web pages. Some examples I can think of are

1) Consider real time limiting length of a text field versus informing users of length restrictions on submitting a page

2) Handling of special characters e.g. $!^*!( etc.

3) Special validation of text fields for specific text field types e.g. email fields, phone number fields etc.

It would be great if there was a document that covers guidelines such as these.

Comment: Sounds more like a usability question http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Type of input field**
Provide the appropriate type of input field based on what is being requested. Each type of input field has its own characteristics, which users are accustomed to. For instance, use radio buttons if only one option of several is permitted, and check boxes if multiple choices are allowed.

**Customizing input fields**
Do not invent new types of input fields. This was common in the early days of Flash websites, and it seems to be making a comeback; I have seen some odd input fields implemented with jQuery. Simple is often the most useful. Keep input fields as close to their unaltered HTML rendering as possible.

**Restricting the format of input fields**
If you need to restrict the format of data inputted by users, then at least do so in a way that won’t irritate users. For example, instead of displaying MM/DD/YYYY next to a text field for a date, consider using three drop-down fields or, better yet, a calendar control.

**Mandatory vs. optional fields**
Clearly distinguish which input fields cannot be left blank by the user. The convention is to use an asterisk (*). Any symbol will do, as long as a legend is visible to indicate what it means (even if it’s an asterisk).
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/08/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/

Text fields allow the user to input text. They can be single line, with or without scrolling, or multi-line, and can have an icon. Touching a text field places the cursor and automatically displays the keyboard. In addition to typing, text fields allow for a variety of other tasks, such as text selection (cut, copy, paste) and data lookup via auto-completion. See Patterns > Selection for text selection design.

The type of text field determines what kind of characters are allowed inside the field and may prompt the virtual keyboard to optimize its layout for frequently used characters. Common types for which you should optimize include number, text, email address, phone number, person’s name, username, URL, street address, credit card number, PIN, and search query.

To read more visit http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html